# How to make top and bottom of div triangle with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Right now I got this:

[image: http://www.xup.to/dl,13319328/example.jpg]

Its three DIVs. The first one at the top is Triangle-Shaped, the one in the Center is a normal DIV without any shape and the third one, at the bottom is Triangle-Shaped again. All shapes are formed via CSS (border-transparency)

I would like to combine the three DIVs into one without losing the Shape of the whole construct. Is this possible?

Here is my HTML-Code:

```
<div id="triangle1"></div> /* triangle at the top */
<div id="center">
<p>Text Text Text</p>
<div id="triangle2"></div> /* triangle at the bottom */
```

And here is the CSS-Code:

```
#center {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    top: 100px;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
}

#triangle1 {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 1143px 80px 0px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #E0E0E0 transparent;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    position: absolute;
}

#triangle2 {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 312px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 80px 0 0 1152px;
    border-color: #E0E0E0 transparent transparent transparent;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I would like to combine the code of #triangle1 and #triangle2 into #center without losing the look it has right now (as seen on the Screenshot).
But how?

Thank you so far.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jfcrob6h/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You could use CSS transforms to accomplish this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

```
transform: skewY(3deg);
```

Transforming the parent has a side effect, its descendent (paragraph with text) will also be skewed. An easy fix is to reverse the transform on a descendent element.

[Here is a quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jzelenkov/tpzoo13r/1/).

[You might need to add browser-specific prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) for older browsers:

```
-moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
-webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
-o-transform: skewY(3deg);
-ms-transform: skewY(3deg);
transform: skewY(3deg);
```